# Nav Bar does not fill the whole page

Tags: html, css, navigation, nav

Hello I made a nav bar and it does not fill the whole page. There is a tiny spot missing on the edge as you can see in the picture

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

l

So this is the code for the navbar

And here is the CSS for it

```
.navbar {
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 0px;
    background-color: #191d29;
    box-shadow: 0 2px #23253b;
}
```

Why is it like that ?

Looking forward to your answers!

Comment: Please consider creating a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your current issue with [stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) for us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should add to body{margin:0;}

Answer (score 1):

There are three solutions

```
body {
  margin:0;
}
```

or

```
.navbar {
  font-size: 0;
}
```

or

```
.navbar .top-advertise-container{
    margin-right: -4px;
}
```

Comment: sadly both solutions didn't work but the one of godfather worked

Comment: @noobonstack Ok. I will add his decision in response so as not to mislead anyone.